# Toast in Fragment ( No syntax but no show when running the code)

Tags: android, toast

I am a newbie for android development. Recently, i faced a problem when i want to use toast and alert dialog.

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have tried `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` instead of only `getActivity`

both code have no syntax error but show nothing when i run

More code:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {
...
 ....  onCreate... 
....   GetData();...
..
```

In GetData()

```
inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String error = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(error);
            String test123 = data.getJSONObject("error").getString("code");

            RegisterFragment register = new RegisterFragment();
            register.makeToast(test123);
...
..
}
```

In makeToast function:

```
public void makeToast(String error){
    Log.v("error",error);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "missing input",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }


}
```

Comment: `getAllictaionContext` you mean `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: what is the problem you are having? Please provide us with some context about your problem

Comment: and you know for a fact that this line is executed?

Comment: i type that in a function with log so as to test if the function is executed

Comment: it proves that the function is really executed but still no show

Comment: please post more code around where this is being run

Comment: Assuming `GetData()` is run on a different thread a `Toast` needs to be done on the UI thread

Comment: Actually getData() is a function for receiving server data
,  makeToast(error) is called and make Toast according to different errors received

Comment: And what do u mean by different thread? I am new to this framework ><

Answer (score 0):

The toast can only be shown on a UI Thread. Since you are making a network call the response must be running on a background thread. change your method to

```
public void makeToast(String error) {
    Log.v("error", error);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "missing input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below ? Actually I have faced same issue 1 month ago, I have solved by below code:

```
new CountDownTimer(2000,2000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      makeToast("Your Error Message");
    }
}.start();
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegisterFragment register = new RegisterFragment();
register.makeToast(test123);
```

This is your problem. You have just created an instance of `RegisterFragment`, but it is not attached to an `Activity` at this point. Therefore, the `getActivity()` call within `makeToast()` will return `null`.

Comment: TT  then wt should i do

Comment: Where is this `getData()` method being executed? To run a `Toast`, you will need a `Context` reference. I would suggest just delivering the error code back to your active `Fragment` instance (assuming `getData()` must be running in a background thread) and from there, show the `Toast`, as your `Fragment` should be attached to an `Activity` at that point.

Comment: Is it possible to get Context reference in makeToast() ?

Comment: @waichiu0811 you can either provide a `Context` parameter, or wait until after the fragment is attached (`onAttach()` will be invoked) to the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort ><  but i am reli new to Android .. i find it difficult to understand TT